# How to Send One Variable from one Fragment to other Fragment in One Activity...?

Tags: android

### **How to use fragment value in next proceeding fragment in view pager**

- I am using step indicator in registration
- And i am saving shop name and module in fragment2
- And i want that shop name and module in fragment3 to show

Comment: can you please post your requirements in details.

Answer (score -1):

If both fragments are running (onResume) then they can communicate with an interface or a broadcastreceiver. Interface is the most common one.